# Watson NLU - Not enough text provided for language detection

Tags: java, ibm-watson, watson-nlu

I am working with Watson NLU and trying to sentiment analysis on some text. The problem is that some text is too small for it to detect what language it is (E.g: Excellent service).Is there a way for me to specify that if language detection isn't possible, it should consider it English?

The snippet of my NLU (Java) is this:

```
SentimentOptions sentiment = new SentimentOptions.Builder()
    .targets(targets)
    .document(true)
    .build();


Features features = new Features.Builder()
    .sentiment(sentiment)
    .build();


AnalyzeOptions parameters = new AnalyzeOptions.Builder()
    .text(text)
    .features(features)
    .build();

AnalysisResults response = service
    .analyze(parameters)
    .execute();

String mySentiment = response.getSentiment().getDocument().getLabel();
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the Official API Reference documentation, you need to specify the `language` parameter in your `POST` request.

See more about these parameters on [Watson Developer Cloud - Github](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/java-sdk/blob/develop/natural-language-understanding/src/main/java/com/ibm/watson/developer_cloud/natural_language_understanding/v1/NaturalLanguageUnderstanding.java#L150) - Java SDK.

Explanation of the API Reference - NLU:

- **language** (string): ISO 639-1 code indicating the language to use for the analysis. This code overrides the automatic language detection performed by the service. Valid codes are ar (Arabic), en (English), fr (French), de (German), it (Italian), pt (Portuguese), ru (Russian), es (Spanish), and sv (Swedish). For more information about which features are supported in each language, see this [table](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/natural-language-understanding/language-support.html).

**Example of how it works:**

parameters.json file example:

```
{
  "text": "Excelent service",
  "features": {
    "semantic_roles": {}
  },
  "language": "en"
}
```

The cURL example:

```
curl -X POST \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-u "{username}":"{password}" \
-d @parameters.json \
"https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/natural-language-understanding/api/v1/analyze?version=2017-02-27"
```

Probably your example (you did not specify your programming language, so):

```
AnalyzeOptions parameters = new AnalyzeOptions.Builder()
    .text(text)
    .features(features)
    .language('en')
    .build();
```

- Official reference [Natural Language Understanding](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/natural-language-understanding/overriding-language-detection.html#overriding-language-detection)
- Language support for use [NLU](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/natural-language-understanding/language-support.html).

Comment: I'm sorry. I have mentioned it now. It is Java.

Comment: So, try my follow example. And if works, **mark** the answer and help others with the same doubt, following the [Guide for use StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: I should point out that this enforces the language you specify rather than use it as a default language in case it cannot detect a language.

Comment: Exactly. If you do not specify the language, NLU will try to detect automatically.

Comment: Yes. But this brings about the problem that the text that is in French are treated as English. As I have only a couple of those, that's not entirely a problem for me. But pointing it out for others.

Comment: Yeah, and this information is valued for another Question/answer